# change div size depending on other div size

Tags: html, height

I have a div with four other divs inside.

```
<div class="content" style="height: 248px">
    <div class="info" style="height: 16px">Information</div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="excerpt">Excerpt</div>
    <div class="social" style="bottom: 0; position: absolute; height: 20px">Social</div>
</div>
```

Title div is dynamic. How to set Excerpt div's height depending to title height? All my four divs have to fit 248 px height. Also i need to add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to excerpt div.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with JavaScript

```
$(".article_big_content").each(function() {

    var big_title_height = $(this).children(".article_big_title").outerHeight();

    var big_excerpt_container_height = 250 - 16 - 20 - big_title_height;

    $(this).children(".article_big_text").children("p").css("height", big_excerpt_container_height);});
```

Then i used dotdotdot.js to add ellipsis in the end of text.